# How to use full_join/Reduce on multiple datasets AND have custom suffixes?

Tags: r, join, merge, reduce

I've been trying to achieve merging/joining three datasets of varying and overlapping rows and columns all day.
Now I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8NxjZCrzQY
with moderate success.
The suffixes that I specified unfortunately only show up for the first two data sets and not the third (D3). These columns just have their "normal" name, i.e. "var1" instead of "var1.a3".
Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

```
 DATA <- list(D1, D2, D3)
DATAMERGE <- function(df1, df2){                             
  merge(df1, df2, by = "email", suffixes = c(".a1",".a2",".a3"))
}
RESULT<-Reduce(DATAMERGE, DATA)                                   
View(RESULT)
```

Comment: Could you provide samples of `D1`, `D2` and `D3` used in your question?

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to add the suffixes by renaming the columns of your datasets before merging the datasets. To this end I make use of `mapply` to loop over your list of datasets and a vector of suffixes.

As you provided no data I use `iris` as example dataset whereby I merge on `Species`:

```r
DATA <- list(D1 = iris, D2 = iris, D3 = iris)
suffixes <- c(".a1",".a2", ".a3")

DATAMERGE <- function(x, y) {
  merge(x, y, by = "Species")
}
DATA <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  z <- !names(x) %in% c("Species")
  names(x)[z] <- paste0(names(x)[z], y)
  x
}, DATA, suffixes, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
RESULT <- Reduce(DATAMERGE, DATA)

head(RESULT)
#>   Species Sepal.Length.a1 Sepal.Width.a1 Petal.Length.a1 Petal.Width.a1
#> 1  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 2  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 3  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 4  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 5  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 6  setosa             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#>   Sepal.Length.a2 Sepal.Width.a2 Petal.Length.a2 Petal.Width.a2 Sepal.Length.a3
#> 1             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             5.1
#> 2             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             4.9
#> 3             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             4.7
#> 4             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             4.6
#> 5             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             5.0
#> 6             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2             5.4
#>   Sepal.Width.a3 Petal.Length.a3 Petal.Width.a3
#> 1            3.5             1.4            0.2
#> 2            3.0             1.4            0.2
#> 3            3.2             1.3            0.2
#> 4            3.1             1.5            0.2
#> 5            3.6             1.4            0.2
#> 6            3.9             1.7            0.4
```